# can I make the OS believe my RTX 3090 is a RTX 2080 or 2080 TI?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-rtx

We recently bought a new research machine at my university.
I was lucky enough to get an RTX 3090 back in december, before they became too scarce.

We've however run into the problem that a lot of our scientific software is behind the curve on updating to make the card usable (Probably due to the current shortage)

This is sadly making us unable to do some research we otherwise could do.

Can I somehow make my OS believe the RTX 3090 is a RTX 2080 or 2080 TI?

This workstation is currently running Windows 10 enterprise, but might be moved to some linux distro (due to our IT department rules) at some point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah, that sucks. Guess I'll have to wait for software vendors to support the 30 series cards then ;-(